# Länder versus Lande

Tags: meaning, grammatical-number

Gibt es neben der Tatsache, dass der Plural "Lande" abgesehen von Liedern, Gedichten und den Niederlanden praktisch nicht mehr verwendet wird, auch einen inhaltlichen Unterschied zwischen "Länder" und "Lande"?

(Sowie etwa "Worte" zusammenhängende Worte im Gegensatz zu Wörtern in einem Wörterbuch bezeichnet.)

Beispiele für die Verwendung von Lande:

- Niederlande
- Wir sind durch die Lande gefahren ...
- Tragts hinaus in alle Lande ...
- Und Davids Namen ging aus in alle Lande,...
- ... vertilgte sieben Völker in dem Lande Kanaan und teilte unter sie nach dem Los deren Lande

Answer (score 11):

**Niederlande**
ist ein Eigenname. Damit greift jede Diskussion ins Leere.

**Wir sind durch die Lande gefahren**
Das heißt für mich dasselbe wie "Wir sind durch die Gegend gefahren" oder "Wir sind weit herum gekommen". Wenn Franz im total verwahlosten Taxi quer durch Bayern jagt, fährt er auch durch die Lande, ohne das Land Bayern zu verlassen.
"Wir sind durch die Länder gefahren" würde bedeuten, dass man mindestens eine echte Landesgrenze überquert hat.

**Tragts hinaus in alle Lande**
Heißt: "Verkündet es" oder "Macht es bekannt". Da geht es darum eine Nachricht möglichst weit zu verbreiten. Wenn sich die Nachricht nach dieser Aufforderung nur in einem einzigen großen Land (z.B. Russland) verbreitet, kann das durchaus in Ordnung sein. "Tragts hinaus in alle Länder" würde explizit verlangen, dass man die Nachricht weltweit verbreitet.

**Und Davids Namen ging aus in alle Lande**
"in alle Lande" hatten wir schon im Beispiel davor.

**ertilgte sieben Völker in dem Lande Kanaan**
Das ist Dativ Singular und kein Plural.

**und teilte unter sie nach dem Los deren Lande**
Nochmal Dativ Singular.

Für mich hat "die Länder" eine strenge politische bzw. geographische Bedeutung während "die Lande" eher ein poetischer und antiquierter Begriff ist, der nicht so streng an reale politisch abgegrenzte Länder geknüpft ist.

Comment: "In dem Lande Kanaan" war lediglich Teil der Phrase, die klar zeigt, dass "deren Lande" eben nicht Dativ Singular ist (es handelt sich nämlich um die Lande der sieben Völker).

Answer (score 6):

Der [Dudeneintrag zu "Land"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Land) macht's m.E. ziemlich klar, allerdings muss man ein bisschen scrollen, nämlich zur Bedeutung Nr. 3 und dann zur 5:

> [...]
>
> 3
>      nicht näher abgegrenztes Gebiet, Gelände; Landstrich, Gegend
>
> Grammatik > 
>      veralteter, noch dichterisch, gelegentlich scherzhafter Plural: Lande
>
> [...]
>
> 5
>
> politisch selbstständiges, von Grenzen umgebenes Gebiet; Staatsgebiet; Staat
>
> Grammatik >
>     Plural Länder

- "**Lande**" ist also der Plural von "Land" im Sinne von Gegend,
  Landstrich. (Ich vermute, dass sich "veraltet" nicht darauf bezieht, dass es sich um einen veraltetes Synonym von "Länder" handelt, sondern dass der Plural von Land in diesem Sinn nur noch selten benutzt wird, weil man das Wort in dieser Bedeutung mittlerweile als Singularetantum verwendet - zumindest
  habe ich diesen Eindruck)
- "**Länder**" ist der Plural von "Land" im Sinne von nationales Gebiet.

[Den Dativ "Lande" klammere ich aus...]

**Nachtrag**:
Nachdem ich jetzt drüber geschlafen habe, fällt mir auf, dass das Ganze tatsächlich dem gleichen Muster zu folgen scheint, wie "Wörter" und "Worte". Auch hier sind ja schon im Singular unterschiedliche Dinge gemeint: auf der einen Seite ein einzelnes Wort ("das Wort des Jahres" als kleinste sprachliche Einheit und auf der anderen ein oder mehrere Wörter ("das Wort zum Sonntag") in speziellem Hinblick auf den Inhalt, Sinn" <sup>[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Wort)</sup>

Answer (score 4):

Sowohl im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Land) als auch in [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=Lande) als auch im [Synonymischen Wörterbuch](http://www.textlog.de/synonyme-lande-laender.html) wird "Lande" als veralteter Plural von "das Land", also "die Länder", ausgewiesen. Somit besteht kein inhaltlicher Unterschied zwischen "Lande" und "Länder".

Heute kommt "Lande" vor allem noch in Gedichten und Redewendungen vor, wie z. B. "zu Lande und zu Wasser" (Einzahl), "Mädchen vom Lande". Ferner gibt es noch "hierzulande" und "hier zu Lande" (siehe [Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-hierzulande-hier-zu-lande-a-323692.html)).